# JSON to multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON data as follows

```
 '{"item_id": "0", "start": "2015-06-01 00:00:00", "target": [1.5, 1.545, 6.79, ]}\n{"item_id": "1", "start": "2015-06-01 00:00:00", "target": [254.7725, 136.0975, 181.28, 167.09, 206.25, 147.2075, ]}\n{"item_id": "3", "start": "2015-06-01 00:00:00", "target": [361.13, 254.925, 160.05, 0.0, 255.915, 95.37, 133.32, 297.33, 99.275, 357.5, 43.12, 118.58, 99.0, 348.48, 79.2, 141.625]}'
```

How do I create a list of dictionaries from this JSON?

Comment: Can you be more specific, which shape should it have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's some trailing commas in some of the lists, but removing those, you can use `.split()` to split the string into individual JSON blobs, and then apply `json.loads()` to each of those blobs as you would with any other JSON string:

```py
[json.loads(item) for item in data.split("\n")]
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 {'item_id': '0', 'start': '2015-06-01 00:00:00', 'target': [1.5, 1.545, 6.79]},
 {'item_id': '1', 'start': '2015-06-01 00:00:00', 'target': [254.7725, 136.0975, 181.28, 167.09, 206.25, 147.2075]},
 {'item_id': '3', 'start': '2015-06-01 00:00:00', 'target': [361.13, 254.925, 160.05, 0.0, 255.915, 95.37, 133.32, 297.33, 99.275, 357.5, 43.12, 118.58, 99.0, 348.48, 79.2, 141.625]}
]
```

Comment: `data.splitlines()` perhaps